# AntiClockWise angle to clockwise angle conversion

Tags: java, math

How to get the degree of clockwise angle from antiClockWise angle. I need to do this in Java. Is there any Java API that can help ?

Answer (score 3):

No.  There isn't an API to do this.  This is simple high-school maths.  So simple that using an API would make your code >>less<< readable and >>less< maintainable.

For the record, the "computation" is `360 - angle`, if the angle is in degrees, or `2 * Math.PI - angle` if the angle is in radians.

(Or ... maybe, you just want `-angle`.  Your terminology - "clockwise angle" and "anti-clockwise angle" is ambiguous.)